# how to match a regular expression like (%i1) in python pexpect

Tags: python, regex, pexpect

I want to use maxima from python using pexpect,  whenever maxima starts it will print a bunch of stuff of this form:

```
$ maxima
Maxima 5.27.0 http://maxima.sourceforge.net
using Lisp SBCL 1.0.57-1.fc17
Distributed under the GNU Public License. See the file COPYING.
Dedicated to the memory of William Schelter.
The function bug_report() provides bug reporting information.
(%i1)
```

i would like to start up pexpect like so:

```
import pexpect 
cmd = 'maxima'
child = pexpect.spawn(cmd)
child.expect (' match all that stuff up to and including (%i1)')
child.sendline ('integrate(sin(x),x)')
chil.expect( match (%i2) i think ; see below sample session  ) 
print child.before
```

how do i match the starting banner up to the prompt (%i1)? 
and so on, also maxima increments the (%i1)'s by one as the session goes along,

```
(%i1) integrate(sin(x),x);
(%o1)                              - cos(x)
(%i2) integrate(log(x),x);
(%o2)                            x log(x) - x
(%i3)
```

so the next expect would be:

```
child.expect ('match (%i2)')
child.sendline ('integrate(log(x),x)')
child.expect( match (%i3) ) 
print child.before
```

how do i match the (incrementing)  integers? 
Basically i need to match the  (%i#)'s  while printing the  (%o#)'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex matches it: `\(%i\d\)`.  If you needed to match the `(%o#)`s just replace `i` with `o` in the needle.